# Azure Availability Set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I am trying to add a VM to existing Availability set and getting below **error**, please help, it only takes if I create new, but my requirement is to add to existing Availability set:

> Failed to validate the selected availability set. Try again or select
>   the "None" option.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.

Comment: Are your VM and availability set in the same region?

Comment: Yes they are in same availbility set, i am using managed availability set

Comment: They are even part of same RG and region.

Comment: Is new VM using a managed disk?